# add a common scope to all models in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.2

I am building an online accounts application where each business has its own data and therefore each table has a field business_id.

Is there a way to automatically add to each Model the condition

```
Model.business_id => x
```

For example if a user did a search for all Transactions containing Project the conditions added would be:

```
Transaction.business_id => x
Project.business_id => x
```

I am guessing that this would be best placed in a behavior as it applies to all but two models

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify query data in beforeFind(), which can be within a behavior as well

in your models:

```
$actsAs = array('BusinessCondition');
```

The behavior would be something like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class BusinessCondition extends ModelBehavior {

    public function beforeFind(Model $Model, $query) {
        $query['conditions'][$Model->alias . '.business_id'] = AuthComponent::user('business_id');
        return $query;
    }
}
```